# SQL Server : Insert cursor within stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm new to SQL Server and was given a task where I have to use cursor to duplicate records for Phone Link table. Other tables I have managed to duplicate without needing to use cursor. However I have primary key constraint problem with Phone Link table. Will someone please assist me? Thank you. Following is my stored procedure. Intake parameter is comp_companyid. My requirement is to duplicate every column into the same table and generate new primary key & foreign key.

P/S:

- EntityID = 5 (Company)
- EntityID = 13 (Person)

As I have person phone & person phone link to add on afterwards as well. But I just need to solve this first then I can refer to this when I'm doing person phone.

Also, one company can have multiple person, address.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DuplicateCompanyInfo]
    @Comp_CompanyId NVARCHAR(80)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CompanyID NVARCHAR(30),
            @PersonID NVARCHAR(30),
            @PersonLinkID NVARCHAR(30),
            @AddressLinkID NVARCHAR(30),
            @AddressID NVARCHAR(30),
            @PhoneLinkID NVARCHAR(30),
            @PhoneID NVARCHAR(30)

    EXEC @companyId = crm_next_id 5
    EXEC @PersonId = crm_next_id 13
    EXEC @PersonLinkId = crm_next_id 31
    EXEC @AddressLinkId = crm_next_id 21
    EXEC @AddressId = crm_next_id 1
    EXEC @PhoneLinkId = crm_next_id 10208
    EXEC @PhoneId = crm_next_id 14

    -- Add Company
    INSERT INTO Company
    (
        Comp_CompanyId, Comp_PrimaryPersonId, Comp_PrimaryAddressId, Comp_Name, Comp_Type, Comp_Status, Comp_CreatedBy,
        Comp_CreatedDate, Comp_UpdatedBy, Comp_UpdatedDate, Comp_TimeStamp, Comp_SecTerr, Comp_WebSite
    )
        SELECT  
            @companyId, @PersonId, @AddressId, Comp_Name, Comp_Type, 
            Comp_Status, Comp_CreatedBy,
            Comp_CreatedDate, '1', GETDATE(), Comp_TimeStamp, 
            Comp_SecTerr, Comp_WebSite
        FROM 
            Company
        WHERE 
            Comp_CompanyId = @comp_companyid

    -- Add Person_Link Without Type
    INSERT INTO Person_Link
    (
        PeLi_PersonLinkId, PeLi_PersonId, PeLi_CompanyID, PeLi_CreatedBy, PeLi_CreatedDate, PeLi_UpdatedBy,
        PeLi_UpdatedDate, PeLi_TimeStamp
    )
        SELECT 
            @PersonLinkId, @PersonId, @CompanyId, PeLi_CreatedBy, 
            PeLi_CreatedDate, '1', GETDATE(), PeLi_TimeStamp
        FROM 
            Person_Link
        WHERE 
            PeLi_CompanyID = @comp_companyid

    -- Add Person
    INSERT INTO Person
    (
        Pers_PersonId, Pers_CompanyId, Pers_PrimaryUserId, Pers_FirstName, pers_SecTerr, Pers_CreatedBy,
        Pers_CreatedDate, Pers_UpdatedBy, Pers_UpdatedDate, Pers_TimeStamp
    )
        SELECT 
            @PersonId, @companyId, Pers_PrimaryUserId, Pers_FirstName, 
            pers_SecTerr, Pers_CreatedBy,
            Pers_CreatedDate, '1', GETDATE(), Pers_TimeStamp
        FROM 
            Person
        WHERE 
            Pers_CompanyId = @comp_companyid

    -- Add Address_Link
    INSERT INTO Address_Link
    (
        AdLi_AddressLinkId, AdLi_AddressId, AdLi_CompanyID, AdLi_CreatedBy, AdLi_CreatedDate,
        AdLi_UpdatedBy, AdLi_UpdatedDate, AdLi_TimeStamp, AdLi_Type
    )
        SELECT 
            @AddressLinkId, @AddressId, @companyId, AdLi_CreatedBy, 
            AdLi_CreatedDate, '1', GETDATE(), AdLi_TimeStamp, AdLi_Type
        FROM 
            Address_Link
        WHERE  
            AdLi_CompanyID = @comp_companyid


    -- Add Address 
    INSERT INTO [Address]
    (
        Addr_AddressId, Addr_Address1, Addr_Address2, Addr_Address3, Addr_Address4, addr_postcode,
        Addr_CreatedBy, Addr_CreatedDate, Addr_UpdatedBy, Addr_UpdatedDate, Addr_TimeStamp
    )
    SELECT @AddressId, Addr_Address1, Addr_Address2, Addr_Address3, Addr_Address4, addr_postcode,
           Addr_CreatedBy, Addr_CreatedDate, '1', GETDATE(), Addr_TimeStamp
    FROM Address
    INNER JOIN Address_Link
    ON Addr_AddressId = AdLi_AddressId
    AND AdLi_CompanyID = @comp_companyid



    -- Add PhoneLink
    -- Declare Variables


    DECLARE @c_PLink_LinkID NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PLink_PhoneId NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PLink_CreatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PLink_CreatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PLink_UpdatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PLink_TimeStamp NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PLink_EntityID NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PLink_RecordID NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PLink_Type NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Phon_PhoneId NVARCHAR(30)

        EXEC @c_PLink_LinkID = crm_next_id 10208
        EXEC @c_PLink_PhoneId = crm_next_id 14


    --Declare Cursor
    DECLARE @getPLID CURSOR
    SET @getPLID= CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,
    PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
    FROM PhoneLink
    WHERE PLink_EntityID = 5
    AND PLink_RecordID = @Comp_CompanyId

    --Open Cursor & fetch 1st row into variables
    OPEN @getPLID
    FETCH NEXT FROM @getPLID INTO @c_PLink_LinkID, @c_PLink_PhoneId, @c_PLink_CreatedBy,
    @c_PLink_CreatedDate, @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, @c_PLink_TimeStamp, @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type

    --Check for a new row
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO PhoneLink
        (
            PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,
            PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
        )

        VALUES
        (
            @c_PLink_LinkID, @c_PLink_PhoneId, @c_PLink_CreatedBy, @c_PLink_CreatedDate, @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, @c_PLink_TimeStamp,
            @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type
        )


    --Get next available row into variables
    FETCH NEXT FROM @getPLID INTO @c_PLink_LinkID, @c_PLink_PhoneId, @c_PLink_CreatedBy,
    @c_PLink_CreatedDate, @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, @c_PLink_TimeStamp, @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type

    END

    CLOSE @getPLID
    DEALLOCATE @getPLID



    -- Add Company Phone
    INSERT INTO Phone
    (
        Phon_PhoneId, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, Phon_UpdatedBy, Phon_UpdatedDate, Phon_TimeStamp
    )
    SELECT @PhoneID, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, '1', GETDATE(), Phon_TimeStamp
    FROM Phone
    INNER JOIN PhoneLink
    ON Phon_PhoneId = PLink_PhoneId
    AND PLink_EntityID = 5
    AND PLink_RecordID = @Comp_CompanyId


END
```

Appreciate if you can tell me which part I've done wrong. Thank you for your time and effort in advance!

Comment: What is the primary key of the PhoneLink table?

Comment: @Dan It's PLink_LinkID

Comment: Why all ids are varchar?

Comment: @Ivan I was following my senior's sample. He declared all the IDs as NVARCHAR as well. I believe that won't affect much right?

Comment: @DesmondChau, I don't see code to generate a new PLink_LinkID value for the new row so of course you will always get a PK violation when copying the value from an existing row.  How do you normally generate the PLink_LinkID value for new rows?  If it's a `SEQUENCE`, you'll need to use that here too.

Comment: `INSERT INTO PhoneLink
(PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type)
   
SELECT  @c_PLink_LinkID, @c_PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, GETDATE(), PLink_TimeStamp,PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
     
FROM PhoneLink
   
WHERE PLink_EntityID   = 5
AND PLink_RecordID   = @Comp_CompanyId`

this is what I used @Dan Guzman

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to edit them and make it in paragraph. I tried but it wont work.

Comment: @DesmondChau, the `@c_PLink_LinkID` value is retrieved for the source row and the same value is used in the `INSERT`.  Since `PLink_LinkID` is the primary key, you will get a PK violation every time.  You'll need to assign a new value to avoid that.

Comment: Sir, can you give me a sample code? I'm lost .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what all of inserted columns mean but if you are inserting many rows you need to generate another unique id for each row. So you have to move ID generation code into cursor body instead of placing it before cursor declaration and call this generator each iteration.

```
...
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC @c_PLink_LinkID = crm_next_id 10208
    EXEC @c_PLink_PhoneId = crm_next_id 14

    INSERT INTO PhoneLink
    (
        PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,
        PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
    )

    VALUES
    (
        @c_PLink_LinkID, @c_PLink_PhoneId, @c_PLink_CreatedBy, @c_PLink_CreatedDate, @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, @c_PLink_TimeStamp,
        @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type
    )


    FETCH NEXT FROM @getPLID
    INTO @c_PLink_CreatedBy, @c_PLink_CreatedDate, @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, 
      @c_PLink_TimeStamp, @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type
END
```

If PhoneID needs to be generated too - you have to place it inside your cursor too.
Also remove PLink_LinkID and PLink_PhoneId from cursors's select since you don't need original values. And, of course, remove'em from fetch lists. Just as shown above.

But,
if my assumptions are correct then you are going  a bit wrong way. If `PhoneLink` table is a table that links some Phones to newly created Entity/Company, then you need to copy Phone first (and generate ID for that record) and after that - to build a link between new Phone_ID and new Company_ID.
Now, if you always have only one Phone per Company (which would be a bit strange) then you don't need cursor. But if you can have several phones per company then you need to generate several new Phone_IDs. Which means, you need to iterate through phones *and* links instead of iterating links only. And the code should look like:

```
...
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC @c_PLink_LinkID = crm_next_id 10208
    EXEC @c_PLink_PhoneId = crm_next_id 14

    INSERT INTO Phone
    (
      Phon_PhoneId, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, Phon_UpdatedBy, Phon_UpdatedDate, Phon_TimeStamp
      )
      SELECT @PhoneID, Phon_Number, Phon_CreatedBy, Phon_CreatedDate, '1', GETDATE(), Phon_TimeStamp
      FROM Phone
      WHERE Phon_PhoneId = @Old_Phone_ID

    INSERT INTO PhoneLink
    (
        PLink_LinkID, PLink_PhoneId, PLink_CreatedBy, PLink_CreatedDate, PLink_UpdatedDate, PLink_TimeStamp,
        PLink_EntityID, PLink_RecordID, PLink_Type
    )

    VALUES
    (
        @c_PLink_LinkID, @c_PLink_PhoneId, @c_PLink_CreatedBy, @c_PLink_CreatedDate, @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, @c_PLink_TimeStamp,
        @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type
    )


    FETCH NEXT FROM @getPLID
    INTO @Old_Phone_ID, @c_PLink_CreatedBy, @c_PLink_CreatedDate, @c_PLink_UpdatedDate, 
      @c_PLink_TimeStamp, @c_PLink_EntityID, @c_PLink_RecordID, @c_PLink_Type
END
```

Note, I returned `@Old_Phone_ID` into fetch list - so you could locate copied phone by id. And last insert-select-phone is no longer needed in this case (and actually is incorrect in many phones case 'cause it's inserting scalar @PhoneID, same for all inserted rows).

Comment: Ivan, I appreciate very much for your effort! But I would like to know how do I declare @Old_PhoneID so that it would take the value of the old value?

Comment: It's `PLink_PhoneId` from cursor's select statement.

Comment: The `INSERT INTO Phone` part, `WHERE PhoneID=@Old_Phone_ID`, did you mean `WHERE Phon_PhoneID=@Old_Phone_ID`?

And I can't just put the @Old_Phone_ID in without declaring it properly.

Comment: Yes, that is Phone_phone_id. Will fix later - now writing from my phone.

Comment: I have edited for you. Can you tell me how do I declare @Old_Phone_ID and what should I declare it as? I'm sorry I'm new to SQL that I may ask obvious questions.

Comment: After I put both of my `INSERT INTO Phone` & `INSERT INTO PhoneLink` into the Cursor, I don't know how to write a proper cursor anymore. What to write in `SELECT`, the first `FETCH NEXT FROM`, and the last `FETCH NEXT FROM`. Please guide me.

Comment: First FETCH is same as second one which is in my answer. You do already have all ID's declared just add another one same way. You may leave your old cursor with fetches as it is but add another variable for new Phon_PhoneID generated by crm_next_id proc.

Comment: Can you kindly write a sample for me? I'm a bit lost and confused. I've tried removing `PLink_LinkID` and `PLink_PhoneId` from cursor select as told, also declared `Old_Phone_ID` the same way as I declared other variables, but it still doesn't work =(

Comment: Btw you are right, I have to copy phone first then link it to company by using phone link table. I have to put both into cursor. But still can't work perfectly.