# SQL - How to insert values while checking condition based on another table? If null generate new ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given a task to use cursor to duplicate tables. (Don't ask me why or suggest me to use other way cause that's part of the requirement of the task given)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DuplicateCompanyInfo]
@Comp_CompanyId NVARCHAR(80)


AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CompanyID NVARCHAR(30),
    @PersonID NVARCHAR(30),
    @PersonLinkID NVARCHAR(30),
    @AddressLinkID NVARCHAR(30),
    @AddressID NVARCHAR(30),
    @PhoneLinkID NVARCHAR(30),
    @PhoneID NVARCHAR(30),
    @PersPhoneLinkID NVARCHAR(30),
    @PersPhoneID NVARCHAR(30)
        EXEC @companyId = crm_next_id 5
        EXEC @PersonId = crm_next_id 13
        EXEC @AddressId = crm_next_id 1



    -- Add Company
    INSERT INTO Company
    (
        Comp_CompanyId, Comp_PrimaryPersonId, Comp_PrimaryAddressId, Comp_Name, Comp_Type, Comp_Status, Comp_CreatedBy,
        Comp_CreatedDate, Comp_UpdatedBy, Comp_UpdatedDate, Comp_TimeStamp, Comp_SecTerr, Comp_WebSite
    )
    SELECT  @companyId, @PersonId, @AddressId, Comp_Name, Comp_Type, Comp_Status, '1',
            GETDATE(), '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE(), Comp_SecTerr, Comp_WebSite

    FROM Company
    WHERE Comp_CompanyId = @comp_companyid
    AND Comp_Deleted is null



   ---- PersonLink Cursor ----------------------------------------------
    -- Declare Variables
    DECLARE @c_PeLi_PersonLinkId NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PeLi_PersonId NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PeLi_CompanyID NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PeLi_CreatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PeLi_CreatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PeLi_UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PeLi_UpdatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_PeLi_TimeStamp NVARCHAR(30)


    --Declare Cursor
    DECLARE PersonLinkCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT PeLi_PersonLinkId, PeLi_PersonId, PeLi_CompanyID, PeLi_CreatedBy, PeLi_CreatedDate, PeLi_UpdatedBy,
        PeLi_UpdatedDate, PeLi_TimeStamp
    FROM Person_Link
    INNER JOIN Person
    ON PeLi_PersonId = Pers_PersonId
    AND PeLi_CompanyID = @comp_companyid
    AND Pers_Deleted is null
    AND PeLi_Deleted is null

    --Open Cursor & fetch 1st row into variables
    OPEN PersonLinkCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonLinkCursor INTO @c_PeLi_PersonLinkId, @c_PeLi_PersonId, @c_PeLi_CompanyID, @c_PeLi_CreatedBy,
                                  @c_PeLi_CreatedDate, @c_PeLi_UpdatedBy, @c_PeLi_UpdatedDate, @c_PeLi_TimeStamp


    --Fetch successful
    --Check for a new row
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        EXEC @c_PeLi_PersonLinkId = crm_next_id 31
        EXEC @PersonId = crm_next_id 13


    INSERT INTO Person_Link
    (
        PeLi_PersonLinkId, PeLi_PersonId, PeLi_CompanyID, PeLi_CreatedBy, PeLi_CreatedDate, PeLi_UpdatedBy,
        PeLi_UpdatedDate, PeLi_TimeStamp
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @c_PeLi_PersonLinkId, @PersonId, @companyId, '1', GETDATE(), '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE()
    )


    --Get next available row into variables
    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonLinkCursor INTO @c_PeLi_PersonLinkId, @c_PeLi_PersonId, @c_PeLi_CompanyID, @c_PeLi_CreatedBy,
                                  @c_PeLi_CreatedDate, @c_PeLi_UpdatedBy, @c_PeLi_UpdatedDate, @c_PeLi_TimeStamp

    END

    CLOSE PersonLinkCursor
    DEALLOCATE PersonLinkCursor



   ---- Person Cursor ----------------------------------------------
    -- Declare Variables
    DECLARE @c_Pers_PersonId NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_CompanyId NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_PrimaryUserId NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_FirstName NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_SecTerr NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_CreatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_CreatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_UpdatedBy NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_UpdatedDate NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @c_Pers_TimeStamp NVARCHAR(30)


    --Declare Cursor
    DECLARE PersonCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Pers_PersonId, Pers_CompanyId, Pers_PrimaryUserId, Pers_FirstName, Pers_SecTerr, Pers_CreatedBy,
           Pers_CreatedDate, Pers_UpdatedBy, Pers_UpdatedDate, Pers_TimeStamp
    FROM Person
    INNER JOIN Person_Link
    ON Pers_PersonId = PeLi_PersonId
    AND PeLi_CompanyID = @comp_companyid
    AND Pers_Deleted is null
    AND PeLi_Deleted is null


    --Open Cursor & fetch 1st row into variables
    OPEN PersonCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonCursor INTO @c_Pers_PersonId, @c_Pers_CompanyId, @c_Pers_PrimaryUserId, @c_Pers_FirstName,
                                  @c_Pers_SecTerr, @c_Pers_CreatedBy, @c_Pers_CreatedDate, @c_Pers_UpdatedBy,
                                  @c_Pers_UpdatedDate, @c_Pers_TimeStamp


    --Fetch successful
    --Check for a new row
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    EXEC @PersonId = crm_next_id 13


    INSERT INTO Person
    (
        Pers_PersonId, Pers_CompanyId, Pers_PrimaryUserId, Pers_FirstName, Pers_SecTerr, Pers_CreatedBy,
        Pers_CreatedDate, Pers_UpdatedBy, Pers_UpdatedDate, Pers_TimeStamp
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @PersonId, @companyId, @c_Pers_PrimaryUserId, @c_Pers_FirstName, @c_Pers_SecTerr, '1',
        GETDATE(), '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE()
    )


    --Get next available row into variables
    FETCH NEXT FROM PersonCursor INTO @c_Pers_PersonId, @c_Pers_CompanyId, @c_Pers_PrimaryUserId, @c_Pers_FirstName,
                                  @c_Pers_SecTerr, @c_Pers_CreatedBy, @c_Pers_CreatedDate, @c_Pers_UpdatedBy,
                                  @c_Pers_UpdatedDate, @c_Pers_TimeStamp

    END

    CLOSE PersonCursor
    DEALLOCATE PersonCursor

END
```

This is my table structure:

Company Table:

```
comp_companyid | comp_primarypersonid | comp_primaryaddressid | comp_name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2              | 2                    | 2                     | company 2
3              | 3                    | 3                     | company 3
```

Person Table:

```
pers_personid  | pers_companyid       | pers_primaryaddressid | pers_name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2              | 2                    | 2                     | person 2
3              | 3                    | 3                     | person 3
4              | 2                    | 2                     | person 4
```

Person Link Table:

```
peli_personlinkid |    peli_personid     | peli_companyid
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2                 | 2                    | 2                  
3                 | 3                    | 3                               
4                 | 4                    | 2
```

Now I'm inserting values into each table in the cursor loop as shown above. I would like to insert the value of `PeLi_PersonID` from `PersonLink` & `Pers_PersonID` from `Person` based on the column `Comp_PrimaryPersonId` from `Company` on something like if the ID exists, use the ID, else generate the next id. How do I do that? Thanks!

I've tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Person_Link
        (
            PeLi_PersonLinkId, PeLi_PersonId, PeLi_CompanyID, PeLi_CreatedBy, PeLi_CreatedDate, PeLi_UpdatedBy,
            PeLi_UpdatedDate, PeLi_TimeStamp
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @c_PeLi_PersonLinkId,(SELECT @PersonID FROM Company WHERE Comp_PrimaryPersonId is not null AND Comp_CompanyId = @Comp_CompanyId),
        @companyId, '1', GETDATE(), '1', GETDATE(), GETDATE()
    )
```

It succeeded in taking the value of person id from company's `Comp_PrimaryPersonID` but the `PeLi_PersonId` duplicated will not generate new ID. How can I do a proper condition check? I would like to do a condition check within the loop that defines: if `Comp_PrimaryPersonID`'s value exists, use the value, if not get next id.Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : Insert cursor within stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538638/sql-server-insert-cursor-within-stored-procedure)

Comment: This is the next step that I need to do. Should I edit the old post and delete this one?

Comment: Your statement `SELECT @PersonID FROM Company WHERE Comp_PrimaryPersonId is not null AND Comp_CompanyId = @Comp_CompanyId` will always return value from `@PersonID` variable. Is that what you are doing intentionally? Or you are trying to get personid from Company table?

Comment: I'm trying to get the personid from the Company table, I'm missing one more condition I think.. Because this will always give me the same value of the `@personid` from `Comp_PrimaryPersonID`, I want it to generate new ID from the `Comp_PrimaryPersonID` when there are 2 persons belonged to the same company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same case as in prior *step* - put them into single cursor. First - copy Person and obtain new personid, second - insert Person_Link with link to newly created person.

If you need to create another Person_Link (which is strange because you just copied **all** of Person_Links) to some "primary" person - you need new Person_Id.

```
(SELECT @PersonID FROM Company 
WHERE Comp_PrimaryPersonId is not null AND Comp_CompanyId = @Comp_CompanyId)
```

In this select you refer old `@Comp_CompanyId` so you could obtain only old Person_Id while you are needing exactly new one (which can be found under `@companyId` id).

But you will not obtain even old id with this select - because it selects constant value of @PersonID variable which is not even initialized before this select thus contains some garbage from previous places of usage.

Anyway, you already lost relation with *primary* person for new company at that moment because of the very first insert into `Company` - its newly generated Comp_PrimaryPersonId value links to nothing.

One way to solve it is to check inside of cursor whether `@c_PeLi_PersonId` is same as **old companies'** `Comp_PrimaryPersonId` and to update **new companies'** `Comp_PrimaryPersonId` field with @PersonId value. Store old companies' Comp_PrimaryPersonId into variable at the beginning of your script and use it in cursor.

Comment: Thanks it kinds solves my confusion. Think I can get a clearer pic now

Comment: On the second thought, I would like to do a condition check within the loop that defines: if `Comp_PrimaryPersonID`'s value exists, use the value, if not get next id. after using set back to null. Can you teach me how?

Comment: Do you mean that there are some companies which do not have corresponding record in `Person_Link` for `Comp_PrimaryPersonId `?

Comment: Yes assume that, and I believe setting the value back to null afterwards will always let the condition generates new id, which will avoid constraint when there are 2 persons belonged to the same company.

Comment: you may append them to cursor: `union all SELECT NULL, Comp_PrimaryPersonId as PeLi_PersonId, Comp_CompanyId, NUll, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM Company c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 from Person_PersonLink ppl WHERE ppl.PeLi_PersonId = c.Comp_PrimaryPersonId)` and proceed everything as before with checks for NULLs

Comment: add to cursor - `DECLARE PersonLinkCursor CURSOR FOR ...`

Comment: Why use `ppl` and `ppl.Peli_PersonId`? We can assume the value on our own is it?

Comment: As you said you need to add link to primary person only if it does not exists. That what `exists` is there for.

Comment: Can you write a full working code for me within this cursor? I'm lost.. again.. Appreciate if you can edit your answer and add on a full coding.